# Why doesn't adding 2 "space" characters work when attempting to create a line break? EDIT: Because we're children.

Tags: support, feature-request, comment

I've tried it repeatedly in comments and for the life of me I cannot get it to work. I've even tried just manually adding a "<"br/">" (Of course it works in the actual question field, but I'm specifically referring to the comments.), but to no avail.

Is this functioning as designed or am I missing something?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'd like to have words with whoever made the decision to disallow line breaks in comments.

Comment: you can always $$ $$ trick it with '\$\$ \$\$'  (but the break is huge)

Comment: I see, thanks for the advice Surb, I'll use it sparingly though.

Comment: @Surb Or you can use `$\tag*{}$` $\tag*{}$ which is how I created the blank line above..

Comment: When I have two thoughts I want to express in one comment I separate them like so: // I stole this idea from [run-in quotations of poetry](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch13/ch13_sec032.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/add-syntax-highlighting-and-line-breaks-to-comment-formatting) for the feature request and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50444/comments-dont-have-formatting-tags-or-line-breaks) for the confirmation that it is not supposed to be possible.

Please don't use MathJax workarounds unless *absolutely* necessary (I can't think of such a case offhand), because that increases the JavaScript slowdown when loading a webpage.

Comment: Good lord, that is obscene. Are we really such children that a character limit isn't good enough to prevent massive essays? Line breaks are arguably the number 1 supplemental characteristic for readability. I don't need to write an essay, I'd just like to separate my ideas logically.

Comment: The workaround is to post

Comment: two comments (@Theo)  (I'm not saying it's a *good* workaround, just saying it is one.)

Comment: That's fair, but I doubt the others in the thread want their phones/computers going off with an extraneous notification every time I feel like separating my ideas.

Comment: @Theo I'd guess you will post those comments close in time so it should not be anissue.

Comment: Regardless of time posted this would duplicate the sound/vibration from mobile devices. What's more in an active thread if your next post took even a moderate time to compose the chance of someone else posting a reply between then and thus causing a discontinuity between your thoughts. Obviously there are many issues, all of which could be solved by enabling line breaks.